# Display all events on a calendar

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar

We have a calendar on a page and if there are more than three events on the calendar it hides additional events then displays an arrow with "1 more item" to expand the calendar. Is there a way to override this to display all events on the calendar? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jQuery` and run the below script after DOM is ready

```
function expandCalCheck() {
  var a=$("a.ms-cal-nav", $("div.ms-acal-rootdiv:last>div")).get(0);
  if (a) {
    for (var r=0; r<6; r++) {
        var a=$("a.ms-cal-nav", $("div.ms-acal-rootdiv:last>div").get(r)).get(0);
        if (a) {
            if (a.innerText.indexOf("more") >= 0) {
                a.click();
            }
        }
    }
  }
  jQuery('.ms-acal-ctrlitem').hide();
}
```